# CSS background issue on mobile Safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, safari

I am trying to create a fullscreen div, up until now it works perfectly on chrome, firefox and safari, but on ipad and iphone the background image and the size of the div blow out of proportion.
Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div class="intro">
 (content)
</div>
```

CSS

```
.intro {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("../img/background.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     height: 100%; 

}
```

How can I fix this issue on mobile Safari?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Media Queries to manipulate the look of your site for different resolutions. It is also recommended that you test your sites on actual devices and not on any simulator if that is the case.

Here is a link on how to use Media Queries:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Regards

Comment: yes, I am using media queries, the site looks as I want it to look on different screen sizes, but the main problem comes when it runs on Safari browser on iPad and iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Fullscreen Background.

http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/fullscreen-backgrounds-with-centered-content

Answer (score 0):

As another poster above noted, media queries are good practice for RWD. Full screen sites on desktop can look nice, but often get blown way out of proportion on mobile devices, even large ones like the iPhone 6+. It will probably take a bit of experimentation in the media queries to get it right.

Also keep in mind file size for images on mobile--I recently helped out on a site needing help for a similar issue. Although the display on mobile looked good in the end, it merely scaled down the same images used for the desktop display, which resulted in poor performance (even on 4G LTE). It may take a bit of time, but using mobile-optimized image sets are well worth the trouble.

Comment: I am having some issues with loading time, but so far it runs decently. Are there any more specific media queries? I am defining breakpoints based only on width of the screen